# What image formats are reliably supported in data URLs?

Tags: javascript, html, image

What are all the standard `image/x` Data URLs supported in HTML? Out of the things I've tried I've gotten success with:

- `image/png`
- `image/jpeg`

Are there any more? I am specifically looking for ones supported by the `HTMLCanvasElement`'s `toDataURL` method in most browsers (ones supported by most of the following browsers would be ideal: Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari).

Comment: Are you asking which `image/*` content types are registered with IANA, or which ones work in a particular method? Typically the HTML standard will not define anything specific, and if the browser supports a format, then HTML can support it.

Comment: @tripleee I'm not very good at technical terms, but basically what I think you mean is I am asking what formats are supported by most modern browsers like Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari. They of course don't all need to support it but ones supported by Chromium browsers and Firefox would probably be ideal since that is what most people use.

Comment: The official registry is at https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only image format that `toDataURL` must support according to the [HTML Living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#serialising-bitmaps-to-a-file) is `image/png`. If an unsupported file format is requested a `data:image/png` URL can be returned by default.

MDN's [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) documentation includes

- `image/jpeg` and
- `image/webp`

in the [syntax description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL#Syntax) for the `encoderOptions` parameter. It also includes the information that `webp` is supported in Chrome without mention of other browsers.

As I understand it you can rely on `image/png` support and generally assume that `image/jpeg` support exists in current browsers. While it is certainly possible to create a data URL from a string containing SVG source code, serializing canvas bitmaps to `image/svg+xml` data URLs would require canvas objects to remember how how the image data it holds was drawn (which they do not).

In answer to the question, `data/png` support is required, `data/jpeg` support is ubiquitous and `data/webp` support is probably best regarded as patchy.